# How to build a curved menu with jQuery UI (or other Javascript library)?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, user-interface, user-controls

Is there a jQuery UI plugin (or other Javascript library) to build a curved-menu like [Stacks in OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3739) or a [flow menu](http://activeden.net/item/flow-menu-xml-driven-html-flash-menu/full_screen_preview/140273)?

Or, how would one accomplish this with CSS and JavaScript alone (assuming I can do the math)? Is this possible through DOM manipulation, or does it require something like [WebGL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL)?

**EDIT:** I'll also accept other fancy menu effects offered by jQuery plugins, if they're reasonably awesome looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The stack's on this page](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/358_jquery/example%20files/all-examples.html) are very close to what I'm seeking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using HTML5 . See these examples  http://html5example.net/entry/examples/html5-examples-and-demos-collection-1
see pi-menu example

Comment: Hmm the pie menu doesn't work for me, in Chrome or IE 9. I see an empty rectangle, which populates with wonky graphics on a click. Do you have a direct link?

Comment: Ok, I see it in FF4 now. But it's not what I'm looking for. See the flow menu link above... when hovering over a menu, it should popup and bend to one side. Just like Stacks.

Comment: Link in answer seems outdated.